# Get multi parameter values one-time from chrome.storage.local

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I wanna inject a content script to pages with a method with two parameters. Since the `Chrome.storage.local.get()` is **asynchronous**, I have to make sure that all parameters are initialized from the `chrome.local.storage` and then begin to invoke my method.

Now I can get only one parameter every time with code like :

```
var parameter1;
storage.get('parameter1', function(items) {
    parameter1 = items.parameter1;
    if (parameter1) {
        //do sothing
    }
});
var parameter2;
storage.get('parameter2', function(items) {
    parameter2 = items.parameter2;
    if (parameter2) {
        //do sothing
    }
});
```

But this is not enough to call my method which contains 2 parameters:

```
function myMethod(parameter1, parameter2);
```

So how to get and retrieve them ?

Comment: Have you already read the documentation of [`chrome.storage.local.get`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-get)..?

Comment: Seems to be `storage.get({"parameter1": {},"parameter2": {},}, function(items) { //... })`;

Answer (score 4):

If anyone comes back here in 2021 :)

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(["CONST", "user", "devMode"], (res) => {
    reallyAwesomeFunction(res.CONST.PI, res.user.id, res.devMode);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```js
function myMethod(parameter1, parameter2) {
    var details = [parameter1, parameter2];        
    storage.get(details, function(items) {
        alert(items.parameter1 + ' '+items.parameter2);
    });
}
```

Comment: Even better: `var details = {parameter1: default1, parameter2: default2};`